# How to get key from value in Mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, dictionary

I store message id by user id in my database. The code is as follows:

```
async def add_msg_id(self, id, u_id):
    await self.col.update_one({'id': id}, {'$set': {'u_id': u_id}})
```

I want to get id by providing u_id. I'm using this code:

```
async def get_msg_status(self, u_id):
    user = self.col.find({},{'u_id':u_id})
    return user
```

But it doesn't return the id when I use `print(await db.get_msg_status(u_id))` and showing me `AsyncIOMotorCursor(<pymongo.cursor.Cursor object at 0x7fa15e9dd930>)`. How can I solve it please.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
async def get_msg_status(self, u_id):
    user = self.col.find({u_id: u_id}, {id:1})
    return user
```

The first `{}` is the match and the second is the projection (formating)

Comment: I'm getting this error on your code:                                                                         NameError: name '_id' is not defined

Comment: Try without it. As in the updated answer

Comment: I used your updated code but again when executing print(await db.get_msg_status(u_id)) getting AsyncIOMotorCursor(<pymongo.cursor.Cursor object at 0x7f45f51277c0>) and not returning the user id value

Comment: Why are you using `await`?

Comment: Cause my project is asynchronized and is written by telethon framework. The message id has sucessfully been added to the db and when I use user id it sucessfully returns the message id but when I use the message id in print(await db.get_msg_status(u_id)) it returns me the AsyncIOMotorCursor as the user id